# List<Integer> to List<Long> conversion in Java 11 using Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have a list of Integer and would like to convert into a list of Long (or any other type) by using Streams. I tried multiple options but all failed. How do I do that?

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(7);
    arr.add(9);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Long> longList =  arr.stream().map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Won't work as Integer does not cast to Long.

Comment: got it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```java
List<Long> longList = arr.stream()
    .map(Long::valueOf) //or map to any other type/objects with "e -> new..."
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Same as an earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
...

List<Long> longs = arr.stream()    // Stream<Integer>
    .mapToLong(Integer::longValue) // LongStream
    .boxed()                       // Stream<Long>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Long> longs = arr.stream()            // Stream<Integer>
    .map(n -> Long.valueOf(n.longValue())) // Stream<Long>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The latter uses Integer.longValue(), though Integer.intValue() would have done also.
Relying on Integer to int unboxing and then Long.valueOf widening int to long, is too convoluted. Not sure whether there is a speed/memory difference. Should not.

Alternatively with a different data structure for `arr`:

```
IntStream arr = IntStream.of(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
List<Long> longs = arr.asLongStream() // LongStream
    .boxed()                          // Stream<Long>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically you have to map an Integer to a Long.